# How to hide app icon in apps launcher and run in other app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers

I have an android app which must be launch by another app in same device and i want to hide the **first app** launcher icon on andorid,how can i accomplish this ?

Code:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Error Code : Unable to find explicit activity class

What is your solution for resolve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that within your java code. Simply remove this tags from your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

These tags are in your first activity tags in your manifest.

Comment: its not true,my project didn't run in android studio

Comment: Is it in xamarin?

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: Look at your comments, you said that you aren't using android studio, then you said you are using it!!! If you are using android studio, then you should have a manifest file!

Comment: i said my project can't run in android studio when i used your code,finally i use build item in android studio for deploying apk file and  app didn't run android devices

Comment: Its because this way you won't have an starting activity. Your app will just install on the device. After that you can call your activity from another app like you want.

Comment: is it true this code?
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(txt_package_name,txt_package_name+".MainActivity"));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);